# Accommodating any data type when calling a function/object reference in javascript

Tags: reference, javascript

I'm building a utils library for repetitive coding tasks at work and I've ran into a couple questions in the process.

The library is modeled after various [SEAF patterns](http://www.novogeek.com/post/2010/05/27/Create-a-jQuery-like-chainable-JavaScript-toolbox-specific-to-your-project.aspx).
Generic example:

```
(function() {
   var A = function() {
      return new B();
   };

   var B = function() {

   }

   B.prototype = {
    /* Object Methods */
   }

   window.a = window._a = A;
})();
```

If I assign the value to 'A' to the window object, I can successfully call any available     prototype method by calling `_a.object_method();` However, if I call `_a('selector');` it understandably throws a typeError.

The same is true for the reverse, if I assign the window object the function reference `window.a = _a = A;` I can only call it via: `_a('selector');` and the typeError will be thrown when trying to access any object methods.

My question is, what is usually the best way to handle this? If there are any other SO questions that address this issue, please send those URL's my way.

Thanks so much!

Here is a basic fiddle, uncomment the alternating lines to see what I mean.

[fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ktstowell/Hg3KX/)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the difference between `_a` and `window.a` supposed to be?

Comment: Is `_a('HAI').init();` acceptable?

Comment: @georgebrock, no difference, it's just a method for granting accessor symbols to the window like jQuery does, see approx line 9246 of jQuery core.

Comment: @bfavaretto, http://jsfiddle.net/ktstowell/Hg3KX/4/, niiiiiiice. Thank you!

Comment: @Ken This line: `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;`? Note that they prefix both global variables with `window.` to keep everything nice and unambiguous.

Comment: @georgebrock, that was a typo on my part, I do have it like that in my code. Good eye, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call  `_a.init('HAI');` because `_a` does not have any `init` method, only instances of `B` do (and `_a` is just a reference to `A`).

However, after you call `_a()`, you get back an instance of `B`. So, you can do this:

```
_a('HAI').init();
```

Comment: I don't understand, you just commented above saying `_a('hai').init()` and now it's working, but now you're saying it won't work.

Comment: If you have time could you show me a fiddle of what you mean?

Comment: Hey @Ken, I noticed you recently accepted this answer, but I didn't remember the further questions you asked above, sorry. Are you all set? Or do you still need any further explanations? Let me know, I'll be glad to help.